# Can transceiver replace SPI, I2C and other "normal" methods for high speed data transfer between FPGAs? If so, how?

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga, transceiver

SPI, I2C and UART are some well known serial methods for data transfer between devices on the same PCB. However, they all have a data rate bottleneck which is significantly lower than Multi Gigabit Transceivers (MGBT) like the ones used with PCIe and USB among others.

Is it possible to replace these and just use a MGBT for data transfer between FPGAs found on the same PCB? If so, how? Is it also possible to use the MGBT to transfer data from one PCB to another, what guidelines must be followed in this case?

Cyclone V, Cyclone 10 series Intel FPGAs

Comment: Yes, you can use higher bandwidth links for sure. Why wouldn't you be able to?

Comment: I know nothing about how to use MGBT. Absolutely nothing and don't know where to start from and am not sure how hard it is for them to get working. All things like 8b/10b encoding, comma characters, gear box e.t.c used in things like PCIe and USB have made me confused and terrified.

Comment: I don't know a thing about it either, but the answer to your "can you do this" question is definitely yes. If you're working with FPGAs, you probably don't need an external transceiver IC either; you can build that on the FPGA itself. Or just link the two together directly with a properly made PCB transmission line and use some ad-hoc signalling, depending on what bandwidth you need.

Comment: Which FPGA manufacturer and family are you using?

Comment: Intel FPGAs, please see the tags :)

Comment: Cyclone V, or Cylone 10 with latest version of Quartus Prime Standard

Comment: Tags aren't question data, nor are they a family. Please don't add information in comments, edit it into your question. Otherwise, people have to piece the full question together. Thanks.

Comment: My question would be:  how much bandwidth do you need, and what does it look like?  For example:  are you sending a constant stream of octet-based data (like digital video or music), or are you trying to read and write registers remotely, or something else?  Certainly, you can use MGBT if you want.  Depending on what you are using it for, you will probably need to add some sort of framing so you can recover your data correctly.  SPI can be pretty quick, and is a very low-level protocol.  I2C is great for certain things, but high speed data transfer isn't one of them.

Answer (score 2):

There’s no need to use Ethernet protocol between Intel 10nm FPGA’s.

You can use the differential transceivers with NRZ or 4 level PAM4.

Some devices include Forward Error Correction (FEC) and optional/ configurations:

Transceiver channel count :

- 4 channels at 116 Gbps (PAM4) / 58 Gbps (NRZ)
- 16 channels at 32 Gbps (NRZ) /12 channels at 58 Gbps (PAM4) - RS & KP FEC

Comment: Where can I find example design for this?

Comment: any search engine on the web can find it, if it exists

Comment: If google was so helpful, I would not have posted this here :)

Comment: Also, I wonder where do SeriaLite and RapidIO come into this.

Comment: YOu must learn to define the right key words if it exists, you will find it